# What can I use to clean my electric iron with?

Tags: cleaning

I normally just use a butter knife to scrape off any hard debris. But when doing so, it leaves unattractive scratches on my iron blade. Is there anything else I can use to clean my iron with?

**Electric Iron** *for pressing clothes*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salt! You can use it to clean the sticky residue from the bottom of the iron.

- Put a paper towel on your ironing table.
- Pour some salt over it.
- Turn on the iron to its highest setting with the steam completely off.
- Once hot and ready, rub the iron over the salt and the sticky residue will start coming off onto the salt.
- Replenish salt if needed and continue until clean.
- If some salt gets around the holes, just iron a thick towel to get it off.

Most kinds of normal iron sticky residue will come off using this technique. Depends on what got burned there and there could be some that are tougher.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are talking about an electric iron for pressing clothes.

We found a product which is specifically designed for this purpose.  There are several variants but the one we use comes in a tube and is applied hot with a cloth.  It leaves a protective coating so the residue doesn't reoccour straight away.

I don't know if product specific links are allowed in this site but assuming they are, the specific one we use is this; [Faultless Hot Iron Cleaner](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/251661940632?adgroupid=&hlpht=true&hlpv=2&rlsatarget=&adtype=pla&ff3=1&lpid=122&poi=&ul_noapp=true&limghlpsr=true&device=c&chn=ps&campaignid=&crdt=0&ff12=67&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff14=122&viphx=1&ops=true&ff13=80)

Answer (score 1):

Take some baking soda and put on a paper ,then rub your iron with high heated ,repeat this process until the iron'surface is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this!! It is amazing. I have been cleaning the Electric Iron over 5 years with Paracetamol pills and a cotton cloth

1. Set the temperature to the max level
2. Rub a pill of Paracetamol on the hot surface, the pill will melt on the iron surface as you rub. Please make sure you don't touch the iron plate and burn your self during the process.
3. Before the melted content evaporate off, iron the cotton cloth that you have prepared for cleaning.
4. If there are more stains over the surface, repeat the same method until it is 100% clean and clear